# Why does background stop after 1st 'page' when my page needs a vertical scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I tried using jquery to fade the background of my body in and out. After finding out that was impossible (right?) I moved the background image to a div, so I could fade that out.

```
 <body>
<div id="background">
</div> ...
```

Sinde I don't want my content to fade, I kept it seperate (not containing) and slapped 'position:absolute' on it. It works fine when my page is viewed without vertical scroller. This is the CSS that's on the 'background' div:

```
#background {
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-image:url('bin/achtergrond.png');
 background-position:center bottom;
 z-index:-1;
}
```

So the problem is, when I ctrl+zoom or make the window smaller or view it on a small screen, my background doesn't continue after scrolling. I understand why this happens (because the position:absolute doesn't let it interact with the content and it doesn't know how high it all is, **but I don't know how to fix it.**

You can play with it here: http://demensentuin.be/indexgeheim.php

*Ctrl+scroll to zoom in, scroll down: background fail :(*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than set the height and width, set the coordinates, and have the position fixed.

```
#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

That should allow it to stay in place when the content is scrolled over it, and it'll also cover the entire viewport at all times.

Comment: Thanks, this solves most of the problem. But to be complete, what if I would want the image to scroll down as well?

Comment: Then you're getting into forcing the height to be at least 100%, but without letting it expand with content. This is on footers, but you should be able to glean a bit from it: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page